# Mod_rewrite, with exception that refers to another rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to use mod_rewrite on my page and already have some rules

now i want to redirect to artist.php?name=(PARAMETER) except it matches another rule

at the moment i use a "a/" before artist.php because i dont know how to solve this problem
so if i want so see the artist "Alex" ist just have to type domain.com/Alex and if i want to go to the about page i just have to type domain.com/about (just like facebook or twitter)

of course i'm thankfully for each improvement

Here is the .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^cover/([0-9]*)(s|m)?\.jpg$ /cover.php?id=$1&size=$2
RewriteRule ^dl/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /download.php?$1=$2
RewriteRule ^track/([^/]*)\.mp3$ /song.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^my(/)([^/]*)$ /my.php?requested=$2
RewriteRule ^album/(.*)-([0-9]{0,6})$ /album.php?id=$2
RewriteRule ^a/([^/]*)$ /artist.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^a/([^/]*)/music$ /music.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^(artists|about|charts|contact|myprofile|editprofile|mymusic|uploadsongs|logout|genres)$ /$1.php
RewriteRule ^t$ /t.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.com(/)?.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(mp3)$ - [F,NC]

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

p.s.: i'm sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rearrange some of your rules, and add `L` flags so they don't accidentally get applied:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^cover/([0-9]*)(s|m)?\.jpg$ /cover.php?id=$1&size=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^dl/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /download.php?$1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^track/([^/]*)\.mp3$ /song.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^my(/)([^/]*)$ /my.php?requested=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^album/(.*)-([0-9]{0,6})$ /album.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^a/([^/]*)$ /artist.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^a/([^/]*)/music$ /music.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(artists|about|charts|contact|myprofile|editprofile|mymusic|uploadsongs|logout|genres|t)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.com(/)?.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(mp3)$ - [F,NC]

# assume anything else is a username
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /artist.php?name=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/music$ /music.php?name=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

Comment: ok this works perfectly! Thank you! Just a last question if i want to add (for example) /Username/albums, did i need to write the 3 lines for each rule? 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/albums$ /albums.php?name=$1 [L]

Comment: @axeco Yes, rewrite conditions *only get applied to the immediately following `RewriteRule`*, so you need to duplicate them for each rule.